# using mutate, paste0 and case_when in iteration; problem with mutating existing variables with paste0

Tags: r

@r2evans For your request, here is a snapshot of the dataframe
[image: dataframe][image: as]

and the values for dput(head(as)) is as follows (partial)

```
# dput(head(as[, c("AS1_WEIGHT", "AS2_WEIGHT", "AS3_WEIGHT", "AS4_WEIGHT", "AS5_WEIGHT", "AS6_WEIGHT", "AS7_WEIGHT", "AS8_WEIGHT", "AS9_WEIGHT")]))
structure(list(AS1_WEIGHT = c(72, 59, 50, 55.2, 82.1, 50.4), 
    AS2_WEIGHT = c(74.8, NA, NA, 54.8, 84.5, 52.5), AS3_WEIGHT = c(75.2, 
    NA, NA, 55.9, 81.7, 54.6), AS4_WEIGHT = c(75, NA, NA, 55.1, 
    80.6, NA), AS5_WEIGHT = c(75.4, NA, NA, 58.8, 89.5, NA), 
    AS6_WEIGHT = c(77.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AS7_WEIGHT = c(70.7, 
    NA, NA, 56, NA, NA), AS8_WEIGHT = c(73.8, NA, NA, 55.5, NA, 
    NA), AS9_WEIGHT = c(74.5, NA, NA, 54.8, NA, 52)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to mutate existing variables in a loop using paste0, but I keep having error messages:

`Error: unexpected symbol in: "    dplyr::mutate(AS1_WEIGHT = case_when(as$AS1_WEIGHT == '99999' & as$AS2_WEIGHT == '99999' ~ as$AS3_WEIGHT as"`

MRE:
`as` is a dataframe, code looks a bit complicated, but these are cohort datas gathered at 9 different timelines.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr) 
library(ExclusionTable)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(survival)
library(ggsurvfit)
library(gtsummary)
library(zoo)
library(tidycmprsk)

# AA cohort (2 of 3)
## as

num_fu = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
as <- data.frame()
df <- data.frame()
dfs <- data.frame()
data_dir <- 'C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as'

i=1;
assign(paste0("flnames", i), list.files(path = paste0(data_dir, i), pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE))
assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), lapply(get(paste0("flnames", i)),
                                        function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}))
nm <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(eval(parse(text = paste0("flnames", i))))) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), setNames(get(paste0("as", i, "_list")), nm))
df <- Reduce(full_join, get(paste0("as", i, "_list")))
assign(paste0("as",i), df[!duplicated(base::as.list(df))])
dfs <- df

for (i in 2:length(num_fu)){
      assign(paste0("flnames", i), list.files(path = paste0(data_dir, i), pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE))
      assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), lapply(get(paste0("flnames", i)),
                                              function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}))
      nm <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(eval(parse(text = paste0("flnames", i))))) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
      assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), setNames(get(paste0("as", i, "_list")), nm))
      df <- Reduce(full_join, get(paste0("as", i, "_list")))
      assign(paste0("as",i), df[!duplicated(base::as.list(df))])
      
      dfs <- merge(dfs, df, by = "RID", all.x = TRUE)
      dfs <- dfs[!duplicated(base::as.list(dfs))]
            if(length(grep(paste0("AS", i, "_AREA"), names(get(paste0("as", i))))) > 0){
              assign(paste0("fu_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[as1$RID %in% get(paste0("as", i))$RID, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_AREA"))])
              assign(paste0("fu_loss_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[!as1$RID %in% get(paste0("as", i))$RID, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_AREA"))])
              # FU rate
              assign(paste0("fu_rate_", i-1), round(nrow(get(paste0("as", i)))/nrow(as1), 2))
            }
              else{
                  assign(paste0("fu_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[as1$RID %in% get(paste0("as", i))$RID, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_DATA_CLASS"))])
                  assign(paste0("fu_loss_",i-1), get(paste0("as", i))[!as1$RID %in% get(paste0("as", i))$RID, c("RID", paste0("AS", i, "_DATA_CLASS"))])
                  # FU rate
                  assign(paste0("fu_rate_", i-1), round(nrow(get(paste0("as", i)))/nrow(as1), 2))
            }
}

as <- dfs
as <- as[!duplicated(base::as.list(as))]
rm(list = intersect(ls(), c("df", "dfs", "i")))
```

And below is where I am having a trouble (including the parsing error)

```
i=2
for (i in 2:length(num_fu)-1){
  print(i)
  if(i<length(num_fu)){
    as %<>%
      dplyr::mutate(paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT") = case_when(is.na(as[,paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT")]) ~ NA_character_
                                                                as[,paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT")] == '99999' ~ as[,paste0("AS", i+1, "_WEIGHT")],
                                                                as[,paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT")] != '99999' ~ as[,paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT")],
                                                                TRUE ~ NA_character_), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  paste0("D_WEIGHT", i-1) <- round(100*(as[,paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT")]-as[,paste0("AS", i-1, "_WEIGHT")])/as[,paste0("AS", i-1, "_WEIGHT")], 1)
}
```

However,

```
i=2
as %<>%
   mutate(paste0("AS", i, "_WEIGHT") = 1
```

spits out the same error message, while

```
as %<>%
   mutate(AS2_WEIGHT) = 1
```

works fine.

*Expected output would be:*
Every column(as$AS1_WEIGHT ... as$AS9_WEIGHT) with value `99999` will be replaced by the value in the same row, but in the adjacent column.

I saw that using `!!!` might be necessary but I am lost.

Any comments will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data by posting the output from `dput(head(as))` and your expected output of that sample data (preferably as a `data.frame` as well). Thanks!

Comment: refrain from using `for-loops` when using the `tidyverse` packages. The functions already do the iterations for you.

Comment: @r2evans `dput(head(as))` is a long list. `> dput(head(as$AS1_WEIGHT))` returns
c(72, 59, 50, 55.2, 82.1, 50.4)

Comment: @Onyambu I understand, but can you give me some insight please?

Comment: Data too big to include all of it? That's fine (and common), nothing says that you have to give us all columns or all rows. However ... if your problem is how to deal with multiple columns, then please _give us multiple columns_. It doesn't have to be real data, just representative enough so that if we recommend a solution with (say) three columns, you can extend to however-many-columns you have in your real data.

Comment: .. and please provide expected output given the sample data you provide. (Final note: perhaps it's "obvious" some of the time, but it's not always obvious to us that it's clear to you: your second and third code blocks are parsing errors. It can be really frustrating working with questions that demonstrate a different problem than you are actually experiencing.)

Comment: @r2evans I get that my question doesn't have appropriate MSE and expected output. I added some more information just now. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I fixed your data sample so that it was usable. Some suggestions: (1) First and foremost, JonSpring's answer is likely the best you will get. (2) If it does not work for you, then you need to [edit] your question and add your expected output given the data sample (I asked for this before). (3) While you're editing it, please fix the parsing errors, keeping known-wrong code in a question appears lazy.

Comment: "Every column(as$AS1_WEIGHT ... as$AS9_WEIGHT) with value 99999" and yet your sample data includes none of these. Can you please pick a sample that demonstrates your question, and provide the desired output?

Comment: @r2evans I am somehow stuck with this parsing error, which is part of my problem (and questions). And I just did (4), it wasn't a lack of gratitude, a mere unfamiliairity. I will study your comments more thanks !

Comment: Thank you HJ WHY! That is a common reason and I understand, every forum has different expectations and rules of etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the main task here is to replace 99999 values with the value found in the next column to the right. Here, I pivot longer so that the value to the right is the following value (i.e. `lead(value)`) within each `row` group.

Not sure what behavior you want if two adjacent columns both have '99999' values.

```
library(tidyverse)
as <- as %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value == '99999', lead(value), value), .by = row) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Here, my problem is in `mutate(value = if_else ...` where mutate doesn't accept paste0 as a valid column name. I have tried `mutate(eval(parase(text=`, `mutate(get(paste0(` but all failed. `assign(eval(parse(text=` or `assign(get(paste0(` also fails since these aren't compatible with `case_when(`. anyway I will look into `pivot_longer(-row` and `pivot_wider` thanks!!

Comment: if two adjacent columns both have '99999', then I take the value next to it.

Comment: Hello, I added another part of the dataframe as in the original question. I tried your code, but it skims through all columns including `AS1_Weight`, `AS2_weight` ...

Comment: ```Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't combine `RID` <character> and `AS1_AREA` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.``` I get this error when I run your code.

Comment: It sounds like in your real data you have a column called `RID`. To pivot only the columns where the column name starts with "AS", you could use `pivot_longer(starts_with("AS")) %>%` instead of `pivot_longer(-row) %>%`, which presumed incorrectly that `row` should be the only non-pivoted column.